# Submitting a string to database & form validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have two questions but they are interrelated. Firstly I am trying to make my form fields required. I have accomplished this but it seems my form still calls my php script when the blank form is submitted. How can I make my validation not call the php script if the form is empty?

Secondly, I want to store the url of an image into my database. How can I submit a pre determined string into my database? I have only accomplished database submission with forms.

Here is my validation and attempt to send the string to the php script.

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["subform"]["school"].value;
var y=document.forms["subform"]["confession"].value;
if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Please complete the form before submitting your confession.");
  return false;
  }
  if(x=="CWU"){
      $.post('test3.php', $("images/colleges/cwu.png").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#content').html(data);});
  }
}
```

Here is the php script which I am attempting to submit to the image column in the test table.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql="INSERT INTO test (image)
VALUE
('$_POST[image]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "image added";

?>
```

Comment: Quick question... why not just use jQuery or the many plugins for jQuery that make form validation soooo much easier?  In terms of the image, you need to first upload the image and then insert your url into the database.  I would recommend looking into some PHP tutorials on image uploading.  This question is very basic and can be solved with a quick google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent a form from submitting on the client-side before it can even get to the server, you could do something like this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {

    var input = $('#myform input').val();

    if(input == '') {
        //won't allow the form to submit
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
       //do something
    }

});
```

If you want to implement it on the server-side with PHP, you could do something like this:

```
$input = $_POST['val'];

if(!empty($input)) {
    //carry out the request
} else {
    echo "You did not fill out the form!"
}
```

If you went with the server-side option, it would probably be best implemented in an AJAX environment so that the user doesn't even leave the page when the form is submitted, and then get an error message.  This would disrupt the flow a little bit.